# Why can I start a given application using a Windows Service in interactive mode, but not as a service? (Process.Start)

Tags: c#, windows, service, process, process.start

Hello! I am currently writing a simple C#.NET service that stops a given process when a PC loses its wireless connection for 30 seconds. Once the wireless connection returns, it re-starts the process. All of the logic in the service seems sound, and it works perfectly when I run the service on in my Visual Studio dev environment with the target application running from the same directory that exists on the PC where the service will run. However, when I run the service on the remote PC, the application is never restarted upon re-connection to the network. No errors are encountered in the try-catch, either. I have read quite a bit on SO about working directories being an issue, but that doesn't explain why it is working on my machine and not the other. Here is the code I am currently using:

```
try
{
    ProcessStartInfo processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
    processInfo.FileName = @"C:\Path\Application\Application.exe";
    processInfo.WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(@"C:\Path\Application\Application.exe");
    processInfo.ErrorDialog = true;
    processInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    processInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    processInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
    Process proc = Process.Start(processInfo);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    LogTrace.TraceLine("Error re-starting process " + startInfo.FileName + ": " + ex, false);
}
```

Some other notes:

-I have tried are running the service with different users of varying permission levels. Running the service as an Administrator makes no difference.

-UAC is completely off.

-I have tried running the service in interactive mode in Session 0 on target PC using FireDaemon.

Anybody have any ideas on anything to look into?

Comment: don't use process.Start for services, take a look at the System.ServiceProcess namespace documentation and examples.

Comment: @Rob  
Thanks for the reply, but actually in my case, I am trying to end and re-start an application .exe using the service I have written. The re-start of the application is where I am failing.

Answer (score 0):

snippet of a service starter to get you started

```
{
using System.ServiceProcess;
using...

namespace myServicenamespace
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
            ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] { 
                new myService() 
            };
            ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
        }
    }
}
```

myService defined elsewhere as the code you want to have running, including the

```
{
protected override void OnStart() {...}
protected override void OnStop {...}
}
```

Deployment of the service also differs, as mentioned check the rest of the documentation on ServiceProcess to see more.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but actually in my case, I already have written the running service. I am trying to end and re-start an application .exe using the service I have written. The re-start of the application is where I am failing.

Comment: don't forget services often run with different permissions, could that be the problem?  Any output at all on the error (which can be difficult from a service again because of permissions and lack of environment settings, I used the windows event system to get feedback from the service.)

Comment: I've tried running the service as the domain admin (which is an admin on the PC), which is as high of a permission as I can give. Same results. I am not sure where to turn for logging of any errors, because I have a try catch that isn't getting hit, unfortunately. I do see the process starting in Task Manager, but no application window appears

Comment: windows doesn't like opening windows from services even often when "allow interaction with user" is checked.  I didn't need that in my case anyway but I did look into it a while ago - one of the best workarounds was by firing off a scheduled task, as mentioned was long ago but I remember I did get something appearing that way.  (Yes it's a long way aroud to do something simple, seems they made it difficult on purpose.)

Comment: You said _" I do see the process starting in Task Manager, but no application window appears"_ If the service restarts the application when no one is logged on, where should the window appear?  Since Windows 7, services are not allowed to interact with the desktop and Session 0 is isolated.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway there is always one single, same user logged onto this PC. I could see running into an issue if that ever were the case that nobody is logged on though. Good point.

Comment: @Rob I will give the scheduled task route a shot. Thanks for the suggestion.